# routing doesnt work after deployment in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, deployment, angular2-routing

I have created an angular2 app & deployed it successfully.

app starts correctly after taking some time to load & then I am able to navigate to different components.

but when I put direct address in URL as :

```
www.sample.com/about
```

it says 404 error.

even when I am creating bundle using `ng build --prod` , it creates `dist` folder correctly & I am able to navigate to different components using links only.

but I cant access components directly from the URL in my local system also.

I am using `http-server`.

are there any extra configurations required to make it work?

Comment: In my case ng serve works fine by locahost/ doesnot. I kept console.log in my app.component.ts ngOnInit(). This shows in localhost after that nothing happens.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is solved by implementing HashLocationStrategy which adds # to all your routes.
You achieve this by adding HashLocationStrategy to AppModule providers.

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}],
```

and add the corresponding import

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

This solved your problem.

Comment: oficial documentation : https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#browser-url-styles

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Node as an deployment server? Or you are using IIS or similar servers.

My best guess is when you run from the server it is not finding the resource you are looking for in this example `about`. you have to configure route at your server properly.

If using IIS you will have to use URL rewriting or MVC Routing to serve a default resource if unknow resource needs to be served.

In local when you use `ng serve` or use `lite-server` they take care of these unknown paths.

Hope this helps!!

Comment: If I am using IIS , then how can I configure my server for this? @MadhuRanjan

Comment: You may check this [Link](https://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-rewrite-rules-for-the-url-rewrite-module) for URL rewriting or you may setup a default route like this will redirect all route to Home controller in MVC, and you may have content of index file there, routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters*
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", 
        id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);